# Not getting the desired Output for list

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = ["Hello ", "take "]
list2 = ["Dear", "Sir"]

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        print(i+j)
```

OUTPUT:

`['Hello Dear', 'Hello Sir', 'take Dear', 'take Sir']`

But I am getting output as :

Hello Dear

Hello Sir

take Dear

take Sir

Comment: I answered your question assuming you are using python. Please edit your question to add the tag python.

Answer (score 0):

Printing each combinations won't give you a list. To achive that, you need to save every combination you are making into another list. Then, you will be able to print that list, which is the output that you want.

Here you have the resulting code:

```
list1 = ["Hello ", "take "]
list2 = ["Dear", "Sir"]
list3 = [];
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        list3.append(i+j)
print(list3)
```

**PD:** I'm assuming you are using python.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it with list comprehension :

```
list1 = ["Hello ", "take "]
list2 = ["Dear", "Sir"]

res = [i + j for i in list1 for j in list2]
print(res)
```

Output:

`['Hello Dear', 'Hello Sir', 'take Dear', 'take Sir']`

The reason why you code doesn't work is you get the items and print them in every iteration. You should store them in list first, because the output is a list!